# What compiler to use for angular2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I see there are many options to compile typescript and generate JavaScript out of it like babel, typing, commonjs, systemjs, etc.

What is the best and easy one for angular2 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel and typescript are super set of JavaScript they compile to JavaScript using typescript\babel compiler.

Best way to start with Angular is the [Quick Start using Typescript](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). you may write Angular in Vanilla JavaScript.

If you go with typescript, you will be using Typescript compiler.

[SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) is Universal dynamic module loader - loads ES6 modules, AMD, CommonJS and global scripts in the browser and NodeJS.

Right now Angular team seems to be rooting for [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io/), it is also a Module Loader.

you may use [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for your application. This is the quickest and easiest way to start with Angular 2 application

> The Angular2 CLI makes it easy to create an application that already
>   works, right out of the box. It already follows best practices!

Hope this helps!!